# Randomly Generate force layout D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to randomly generate a multiple points with d3js then add and remove the connections randomly while maintaining constant movement. Here is what I have so far:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.a { fill: #1f77b4; }
.node.b { fill: #ff7f0e; }
.node.c { fill: #2ca02c; }

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>



var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .charge(-900)
    .linkDistance(220)
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");
    resize();
  d3.select(window).on("resize", resize);
function resize() {
    width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
    svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    force.size([width, height]).resume();
  }
// 1. Add three nodes and three links.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = {id: "a"}, b = {id: "b"}, c = {id: "c"};
  nodes.push(a, b, c);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: a, target: c}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 0);

// 2. Remove node B and associated links.
setTimeout(function() {
  nodes.splice(1, 1); // remove b
  links.shift(); // remove a-b
  links.pop(); // remove b-c
  start();
}, 3000);

// Add node B back.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = nodes[0], b = {id: "b"}, c = nodes[1];
  nodes.push(b);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
  link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
  node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
  node.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}

function tick(d) {
    console.log('tick')
    var randomX = d3.random.normal(width / 2, 80),
    randomY = d3.random.normal(height / 2, 80);
     d.x = randomX();
  d.y = randomY();
  console.log(d.y);
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}

</script>
```

Most the code I got from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795). Basically I am trying to create something similar to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7833311) example, but instead of using hexbin, I just want to randomly generate and move nodes/circles around. Something similar to the functionality on [this page](https://fbf8.com/), where the nodes are constantly moving and changing links. Any help on how to achieve this functionality would be appreciated. Also here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Qtbh/) of what I have so far.

Comment: So what specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: My code has changed alot you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NPWuu/). The thing I'm struggling with is instead of loading the entire diagram at once I want to load it in slowly, and instead of adding/removing nodes on zoom I'm trying to get the diagram to populate more on downward scroll. So onload it would slowly load more and more nodes, then when you scroll down it would accelerate this behavior.

Comment: Hmm, you would have to create a page that is quite large and then capture the scroll events I guess. I don't see any of this in your code though.

Comment: The zoom event was in the previous jsfiddle. I managed to replace the zoom event with an onscroll event, you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NPWuu/1/). This seems to work when being run full page, but not within the fiddle for whatever reason. Since I had to comment out the .call(zoom) to get it working alot of the original functionality no longer works, such as keydown. So although its close things are still buggy. Also it is not adding nodes over time.